# no_file_data error when using Slack API upload

Tags: coffeescript, slack-api, hubot

I'm getting this error {"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"} when I try to call the slack API to upload. I already have the specified file in ./log.

```
robot.respond /upload (.*)/i, (res) ->
    app_name = res.match[1]
    request = require("request")
    fs = require("fs")
    channel_name = res.message.room

    data = {
        channels: channel_name,
        filename: "#{app_name}.txt",
        file: fs.createReadStream("./log/#{app_name}.txt"),
    }

    robot.http("https://slack.com/api/files.upload")
      .headers(Authorization: 'Bearer slack-token', 'Content-Type': 'application/json')
      .post(data) (err, httpRes, body) ->
        if err
          res.send "#{err}"
          return

        res.send "#{body}"
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the Slack error. Would have been better to just add the error to your fist question, but not worries. Please delete your first question though.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, because the API method [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) does not support the content type `application/json` posts.

For your case you need to post as `multipart/form-data`, with one part containing the file data and one part containing the API parameters including the token.